# Configure Custom Endpoint for Botframework Bot

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to create a bot in C#. How can I set the path for the endpoint.

I tried to do

```
        httpConfiguration.MapBotFramework(botConfig =>
        {
            botConfig.UsePaths(paths => {
                paths.BasePath = "/bot";
                paths.MessagesPath = "/john";
            });

        });
```

But when accessing `http://localhost:7990/bot/john` I do get a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code that worked for me is like below:

```
httpConfiguration.MapBotFramework(botConfig =>
{
    botConfig.BotFrameworkOptions.Paths = new BotFrameworkPaths()
    {
        BasePath = "/bot",
        MessagesPath = "/john"
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint will be hardcoded if you use the provided integration layer, you can change this by not using our integration layer.  There is an example of this in [this project](https://github.com/JasonSowers/v4-simpleWebApp)

**Edit**
Interesting as I had not thought of it from that perspective.  I like the other way because it gives you more open control of your endpoint and allows for multiple endpoints easily, but this would work as well. I was able to successfully change the endpoint of the bot by making a few changes to it.

first I set up my .bot file like this replacing the old path with something different in the 'endpoint' property:

```
{
  "name": "{your botname}",
  "padlock": "{your-padlock}",
  "services": [
    {
      "type": "endpoint",
      "name": "development", // "production" would work too
      "endpoint": "https://{your-site}.azurewebsites.net/bot/endpoint",
      "appId": "{your-app-id}",
      "appPassword": "{your-app-password}",
      "id": "1"
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

then all I had to do was add this into my startup:

```
options.Paths.BasePath = "/bot";
options.Paths.MessagesPath = "/endpoint";
```

Comment: And what role does the `BotFrameworkOptions.Paths` have?