# How to configure a custom endpoint for the Microsoft Bot

Tags: node.js, botframework

Is there a way to implement a custom endpoint for my bot in node.js?. I saw the same for C# but it seems to to be implemented in node.js.

Here is the link to the C# implementation: [Configure Custom Endpoint for Botframework Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624317/configure-custom-endpoint-for-botframework-bot)

A part from this, in the portal there was an option to connect the bot to an azure function, but I don't see it now. Here is the post where is saw it, on the step 3: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2018/04/22/azure-bot-function/

Here is the C# code to implement and get a custom endpoint, the one it would be great to have in Node.js:

```js
httpConfiguration.MapBotFramework(botConfig =>
{
    botConfig.BotFrameworkOptions.Paths = new BotFrameworkPaths()
    {
        BasePath = "/bot",
        MessagesPath = "/john"
    };
});
```

Comment: Are you using SDK v3 or v4? What have you tried yourself to change the endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that a chat bot is just a web app. You can customize the endpoint that your bot uses the same way you would customize the endpoint for any web app. The [Bot Builder Node.js samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.echo-bot/index.js#L45) do this with Restify:

```
// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        // Route to main dialog.
        await bot.run(context);
    });
});
```

If you want your bot to listen on a different endpoint, all you have to do is change `/api/messages` to something else:

```
// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/bot/john', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        // Route to main dialog.
        await bot.run(context);
    });
});
```

To address your other concern, it appears to be no longer possible to create new functions bots, and support for them will soon expire: [Is Functions Bot no longer a recommended Bot Service in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960382/is-functions-bot-no-longer-a-recommended-bot-service-in-azure)