# Can we customize the bot endpoint given from Bot Framework SDK v4 (.net core)

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I am very new to Bot Framework.

Is there any possibility to change the endpoint something like https://[domain].azurewebsites.net/api/messages/{customer_id}.

I have a reusable code that I want to use it with several bots registered in Azure Bot Channel. With the help of {customer_id} I can detect which appId and appPassword can be used to successfully authenticate the bot.

```
services.AddBot<DialogBot>(options => {
            options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(appId, appPassword);

            // Catches any errors that occur during a conversation turn and logs them to currently
            // configured ILogger.
            ILogger logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DialogBot>();

            options.OnTurnError = async (context, exception) =>
            {
                logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception}");
                await context.SendActivityAsync("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.");
                await conversationState.DeleteAsync(context);
            };
        });
```

Any suggestions or help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321571/how-to-configure-a-custom-endpoint-for-the-microsoft-bot